What does this mean - UTC
Many years ago, I mained some eth (I think).
I have a random note in a docs folder with this string (I have hidden the last digits)
UTC--2018-04-29T04-44-48(3).613Z--90e92ae1f83df3753a6764496572XXXXXXXXXXXX
I also mined Doge and some others.
Anyway, I put it into Google, I got this link. How to get private through UTC files in keystore
I did use Geth back in the day with CLI. But I don't think I have anything else like JSON file (is this a JSON file?).
TYSM.

UTC is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time
